# Rearrange 3D array in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have big binary 3D data and I want to re-arrange the data such as it is a sequence of values in order achieved by parsing the original data as sub-arrays of size (4x4x4).

For example, if the data is 2D and I want to re-arrange the data from 2x2 sub-arrays
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k10VZ.png)

I used simple loops for this but just iterating over the loops took way more times, I am trying to to use some numpy functions to do so but I am new to SciPy
My code looks like this

```
x,y,z = 1200,800,400
data = np.fromfile(file_name, dtype=np.float32)
data.shape = (z,y,x)
new_data = np.empty(shape=x*y*z, dtype = np.float32)
index = 0
for zz in range(0,z,4):
    for yy in range(0,y,4):
        for xx in range(0,x,4):
            for zShift in range(4):
                for yShift in range(4):
                    for xShift in range(4):
                        new_data[index] = data[zz+zShift][yy+yShift][xx+xShift]
                        index+=1
new_data.tofile(output)
```

However, this takes a lot of time, any better implementation ideas? 
As I said, the code works as intended, however, I need a smarter, pythonic way to achieve my output

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
x,y,z = 1200,800,400
data = np.empty([x,y,z])

# numpy calculates the shape of -1
out = data.reshape(-1, 4, 4, 4)
out.shape
>>> (6000000, 4, 4, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when I call out.tofile() and compare the files, it doesn't match with the expected file.

Comment: `out = data.reshape(-1, 4, 4, 4, order='F')` may work.

Comment: if I do it on the example I added, this is what I got [ 1  3  2  4  5  7  6  8  9 11 10 12 13 15 14 16], which is not what I wanted

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26117363)

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following test, for smaller data and block size:

```
x, y, z = 4, 4, 4    # Dimensions
stp = 2              # Block size (in each dimension)

# Create the test array
arr = np.arange(x * y * z).reshape((x, y, z))
```

And to create a list of "blocks", run:

```
new_data = []
for xx in range(0, x, stp):
    for yy in range(0, y, stp):
        for zz in range(0, z, stp):
            print('Index:', xx, yy, zz)
            obj = arr[xx:xx+stp, yy:yy+stp, zz:zz+stp].copy()
            print(obj)
            new_data.append(obj)
```

In the target version of your code:

- restore original values of *x*, *y* and *z*,
- read the array from your source,
- change *stp* back to *4*,
- drop test printouts.

Note also that your code adds **individual** elements to *new_data*,
only **iterating** over blocks of size `4 * 4 * 4`,
whereas you wrote that you want a sequence of **smaller arrays**
(i.e. slices) of size `4 * 4 * 4`, what my code does.

So if you need a **list of slices** (smaller arrays), not a single
**4-D** array, use my code.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is what I exactly need, I have updated the question to be more clear

Comment: I missed the wording up, I meant 'not exactly', The code does make the output I want, however, it still follows the loop methodology. and I tried just iterating over nothing (pass) for huge values, and it takes ALOT of time on python, that's why I was looking for pythonic and numpy way to do so